# Filtering all combinations from array - based on multiple values - Typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, filtering

I have array with combinations

For example:

```
[
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"16GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"32GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"64GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"16GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"32GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Blue",
"Capacity":"64GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"16GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"32GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"64GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"16GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"32GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Red",
"Capacity":"64GB",
"Type":"Pro"
},
{
"Color":"Yellow",
"Capacity":"16GB",
"Type":"Normal"
},
{
"Color":"Yellow",
"Capacity":"32GB",
"Type":"Normal"
}]
```

I have dropdowns with all values per Color / Capacity / Type

I want to create an filter, with all possible combinations based on dropdown selections.

I'm stuck, I tried multiple possibilities to solve it, but it seems like I missing some conditions.

This is fired every time when any dropdown is changed:

```
this.combinations = this.combinations
      .filter(x=> 
        (!this.selectedFilter.Color    || x.Color.includes(this.selectedFilter.Color)) &&
        (!this.selectedFilter.Capacity || x.Capacity .includes(this.selectedFilter.Capacity)) &&
        (!this.selectedFilter.Type     || x.Type     .includes(this.selectedFilter.Type))) 
      )
```

And this filtering is limited only to the selected option in the dropdown.

So my current dropdown:

```
[Yellow] - [16GB] - [Normal]
```

But what I want to achieve is:

```
[Yellow,Blue,Red]- [16GB,32GB] - [Normal]
```

How to get all possible conditions from array based on dropdown selection.

I'll be thankful for any advices / directions.

Comment: are you trying to group them based on type ?

Comment: I wonder - do I have to choose on which dropdown I'm willing to group on ?